# Scheduler in Laravel 5 with crontab in my local system does not work

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5, cron, scheduler

When I run 'php artisan schedule:run' in terminal, it's doing what is exptected, but when I configure my crontab to execute it automatically it has no effect.
My code in Kernel.php is:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
            $example=Example::orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->limit(1)->first();
            $example->touch();
        })->everyMinute();
```

and in crontab -e I put

```
* * * * * php /path/to/laravel/project schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I tried executing other commands in the crontab file and the other commands were working. So I suppose that could be something with php but I don't have any output to know whats the problem.

Any idea on how to figure out the problem?

Comment: To make it work:

* * * * * php /path/to/laravel/project/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you path is not complete. You must include Artisan in your path.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So for example:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/laravel_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

See Laravel documentation for more information: [Task Schedule](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#introduction)

**Edit**

If you would like to see the output of your Cronjob then you must remove the following:

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks you were right, I just added artisan and now is working

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the issue is that Cron does not know where PHP is. In such cases, you have to define the path to your local php installation. In my machine,

```
crontab -e
```

has the entry

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/younus/TruckJee/Code/Panel/artisan schedule:run
```

It worked perfectly as planned. Also, to check if your crobjobs are running, use

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

It should show if your cronjob is actually running. (ie)

```
May 23 16:21:01 farveaz cron[1105]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
May 23 16:21:01 farveaz CRON[6812]: (younus) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php /home/younus/TruckJee/Code/Panel/artisan schedule:run)
May 23 16:21:01 farveaz CRON[6811]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```